# Django admin - filter in get_queryset not working

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have this two models

```
class Invitacion(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   host = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Nombre Invitacion")


class Invitado(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   invitacion = models.ForeignKey(Invitacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 ...
```

And registered those in the admin with

```
admin.site.register(Invitacion)

@admin.register(Invitado)
class InvitadoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return Invitado.objects.all()
        return Invitado.objects.filter(invitacion__host=request.user)
```

However this filter does not work(it returns an empty queryset):

```
return Invitado.objects.filter(invitacion__host=request.user)
```

If I filter on the shell it works but not on the admin.
I have an admin group that only has permission to add/change/delete **Invitados**

Comment: What Django-version are you using?

Comment: I'm, using version 
django.VERSION                                                                                                                                            
(2, 2, 10, 'final', 0)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What's the exact problem? Some error? Not the correct behavior?

Comment: @dirkgroten It returns an empty queryset but the DB has the correct values

Comment: The filter is not correct then: `request.user` is not what you think.